# Не парсится json

Tags: json, php, синтаксический-анализ

Пытаюсь вывести данные с [json-страницы](http://capitalcity.silver-bk.com/inf.php?id=109810&short=1)

Пишу:

```
$user_inf = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://capitalcity.silver-bk.com/inf.php?id=109810&short=1'), true);
echo $user_inf['incity'];
```

Но ничего не возвращается. Где ошибка?

Comment: Что падает в нотификацию или ошибку?  
Если хостинг бесплатный, то он не поддерживает обычно протоколы как файловые пути.  
Сделайте:  

    echo file_get_contents("http://google.com");

Comment: Юзаю денвер. :)

    echo file_get_contents("http://google.com");
возвращает гугл.

Ошибок нет. Просто пустая страница.

Comment: Может проблема в странице, которую я пытаюсь парсить?
Создал копию этой страницу, где просто повторяю все данные -- и всё ок.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`json_last_error()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.json-last-error.php) с вашим примером возвращает ошибку '`JSON_ERROR_UTF8`' — беда с кодировкой.

Посмотрите про [`stream_context_create()`](http://www.php.net/manual/ru/function.stream-context-create.php).